# MapInfo to ArcGIS workspace conversion not retaining all map layers in TAB Reader

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, mapinfo

I've recently come across the [TAB Reader](https://tabreader.dataeast.com/en/overview/) extension for ArcGIS Desktop and am using it to convert from MapInfo to ArcGIS. I'm only testing the waters at the moment, as I've been tasked with finding a quicker solution (quicker than recreating from scratch) for transferring workspaces from MapInfo to ArcGIS.

I have a MapInfo workspace with 7 separate maps in. When I go to use the WOR to ArcGIS function in TAB Reader, only 4 of these maps appear in the map list. I've tried removing these 4 maps from the MapInfo workspace, to see if the remaining 3 appear (thought the function could perhaps be limited to 4 maps at a time). However, they didn't show up. These remaining 3 maps don't include anything too drastically different from the 4 which did appear so I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

**Are there any obvious reasons as to why the WOR to ArcGIS function in TAB Reader wouldn't show all maps in the map list?**